# Execute resolvers one by one?

Tags: angularjs

In following code i have two resolvers: `loggedin` and `owner`.

```
   .when('/admin/deals/my-deals', {
        templateUrl: 'views/assessment/assessments_my_test.html',
        controller: 'DealTestController',
        resolve: {
            loggedin: checkAdminin,
            owner: getOwnerByEmail
        }
    })
```

They run parallel but i need first wait `loggedin` and only then run `owner`.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run two asynchronous functions sequentially, they need to be chained:

```
.when('/admin/deals/my-deals', {
    templateUrl: 'views/assessment/assessments_my_test.html',
    controller: 'DealTestController',
    resolve: {
        both: function() {
            var result = {};
            var promise = checkAdmin();
            var p2 = promise.then(function(data) {
                result.loggedin = data;
                return getOwnerByEmail();
            });
            var p3 = p2.then(function(data) {
                result.owner = data;
                return result;
            });
            return p3;
         }
     }
})
```

Both promises need to invoked and resolved in one composite resolver function. The `both` function resolve with an object:

```
{ loggedin: <data from checkAdmin>,
  owner:    <data from getOwnerByEmail>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises.  Now these are special promises for routing and I do not have an environment set up to test this in angularjs but it does work in plain JavaScript.  It's worth trying something like:

```
resolve: {
  loggedin: checkAdminin.then(getOwnerByEmail)
}
```

You will have to chain the two promises somehow or they are going to run asynchronously.